# "Приснился сон": тавтология или нет?

Tags: стилистика

Подумалось: а не является ли тавтологией словосочетание "приснился сон"? Если сон, то понятно, что он приснился, а не случился наяву.))) Не грамотнее ли будет говорить просто "мне приснилось то-то и то-то" или "я видел сон о том-то"?
Спасибо за совет.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нет, тут стилистически все нормально.
Если и тавтология, то не та, с которой надо бороться.
Можно сказать "привидился сон" или еще как-то, но сам сон - "сюжет" некоего ночного видения - никак русскому языку не противоречит. И этот сон может сниться.
Некоторая аналогия - "писать письмо".

Answer (score 6):

Это плеоназм, конечно, но он стал уже устойчивым оборотом,характерным для разговорной и разговорно-поэтической речи, как и некоторые другие: спуститься вниз с горы, окружен со всех сторон, видел своими глазами, бежать бегом;пути-дороги, море-океан, звать-величать и многие другие.

Answer (score 2):

Да, без этой "тавтологии" нам не обойтись. Мы говорим: мне это снится. Нельзя же  "сновидение" в сочетании с глаголом называть только словом "это". Еще я видела объяснение, что сон - это нейтральный сюжет, а то еще могут сниться кошмары.

ОТВЕТ 2. В поэтической речи повтор - это художественный прием, там он называется плеоназмом. Здесь же, мне кажется,  ставится вопрос о том, есть ли в словосочетании "снится сон" излишний смысловой повтор, добавляет ли слово "сон" туда новое содержание.